# Rewrite long URLs to have trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got this code to rewrite directories 1 level deep on the server. It appends a trailing slash `/` if one isn't provided.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*[^/]$ /$0/ [L,R=301]
```

which is working, but how do I force trailing slashes if the URL is several directories deep ....

```
http://example.org/words/more-words/1234/this-is-an-article
```

how can I make all URLs (of variable length) append a trailing `/`?

Comment: What you currently have looks like it would work.  What sort of erroneous output are you seeing?

Comment: @CAustin when i use the example link format above it will load the page with or without a slash on the end -  i want it to redirect to the page with a slash if a user attempts to access it without one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your rule with this:

```
## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```